# Is there any way to set user permission on specific CMS Pages in OctoberCms?

Tags: php, laravel-5, octobercms

I have created an website with OctoberCms and there are some CMS pages like 'about us', 'contact us' and many more.

I want to create a role for such an user who will only be able to edit 'about us' page but not 'contact us' page.

Any suggestion is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I also have similar issue. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: sadly as far as I know there is no built in way of doing this.